# Is there any research on anger and distrust detection (presence and level of political cynicism)?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, reference-request

The undergrad research project I'm working on would require me to detect presence and level of **political cynicism** from reddit posts.
According to definition political cynicism consists of

- anger
- distrust

towards politicians or political institutions.

Does anyone know of existing research relevant for my goal?
I know approaches exist for emotion detection, so the anger component should be no problem.

But how could I model distrust or at least come close to it?

I have access to a large dataset consisting of reddit posts (from politics related subreddits) with labels measuring the political extremity of the user. Political cynicism is one of the most distinguishing features of those on the extreme ends of the political spectrum compared to moderates according to data from psychology, so the data should somehow reflect this correlation, and therefore there should be a some opportunity for a CNN to pick up on it. But would there be a way to then isolate this component?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

I'm a newbie to NLP so please forgive any ignorance expressed through this post.